# SQLAlchemy error - "Please configure one or more attributes for these same-named columns explicitly."

Tags: sqlalchemy

I am brand new to sqlalchemy. Trying to get a query to work and am having issues with a join.

I have two tables both of which have a column named "Id" and I need to join on that table. My code looks like this:

```
table1 = server.tab1
table2 = server.tab2
joined = server.join(table1,table2, table1.Id == table2.Id)
where = table1.createDate > start
results = joined.filter(where).all()
```

This results in the following error message:

> Implicitly combining column  table1.Id  with column  table2.Id  under attribute 'Id'. Please configure one or more attributes for these same-named columns explicitly.

Question is, how do I configure these attributes?

TIA!

Answer (score 2):

With sql soup

```
joined = server.session.query(table1).join((table2,table1.id == table2.id))
where = table1.createDate > start
results = joined.filter(where).all()
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue so I figured I would add the solution I came up with (based on http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlalchemy@googlegroups.com/msg23735.html).  It's certainly not the cleanest thing I've ever coded, but using your example from above, it would be approximately:

```
from sqlalchemy import select
aliased_table1 = select([
    table1.c.Id.label("renamed_id_col"),
    table1.c.any_other_columns_you_want_returned_but_not_renamed,
    ...
]).correlate(None).alias()
joined = server.join(aliased_table1, table2, aliased_table1.c.renamed_id_col == table2.Id)
where = aliased_table1.c.createDate > start
results = joined.filter(where).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

One way about this is to label all the columns in one of the tables, so that you don't have any collision of the column names:

```
table1 = server.tab1
table2 = server.with_labels(server.tab2)
joined = server.join(table1,table2, table1.Id == table2.tab2_Id)
where = table1.createDate > start
results = joined.filter(where).all()
```

table2 ends up being a labeled table, where all the column names are prefaced with the table name, so as not to interfere with the column names in table1.

Answer (score -2):

You can use join feature provided by sqlalchemy,
see the example below, no need to do it manually sqlalchme does it for us,

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, String, Integer, Table, ForeignKey

from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper, relationship
from sqlalchemy.schema import MetaData
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import sessionmaker

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column('user_id',Integer,primary_key = True)
    name = Column('user_name',String(20))

    addresses = relationship("Address",backref="user")

class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'addresses'

    id = Column('user_id',ForeignKey('users.user_id'))
    address = Column('address',String(30))
    pk = Column('address_id',Integer,primary_key=1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    engine = create_engine("sqlite://", echo = True)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)  
    session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()

    u1 = User(name='japan')
    session.add(u1)
    session.commit()
    u1.addresses.append(Address(address='a1'))
    u1.addresses.append(Address(address='a2'))
    session.flush()
    q = session.query(User).join(User.addresses).all()
    print "="*23,q
```

Comment: This workaround avoids the core issue. Still wondering how to do this with dynamically mapped models using SqlSoup.