# SQLAlchemy 'entity' for `add_columns` not backed by a table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm, flask-sqlalchemy

With a SQLAlchemy query like:

```py
result = db.session.query(Model).add_columns(
    func.min(Model.foo).over().label("min_foo"),
    func.max(Model.foo).over().label("max_foo"),
    # ...
)
```

The result is an iterable of tuples, consisting of firstly the `Model` row, and then the added columns.

How can I either:

1. Contribute the added columns to `Model`, such that they can be accessed from each element as `model.min_foo` et al.; or
2. Map the added columns into a separate dataclass, such that they can be accessed as e.g. `extra.min_foo`?

The main thing I'm trying to achieve here is access by name - such as the given labels - without enumerating them all as `model, min_foo, max_foo, ...` and relying on maintaining the same order. With `model, *extra`, `extra` is just a plain list of the aggregate values, there's no reference to the label.

If I dynamically add the columns to the model first:

```py
Model.min_foo = Column(Numeric)
```

then it complains:

> Implicitly combining column modeltable.min_foo with column modeltable.min_foo under attribute 'min_foo'.
> Please configure one or more attributes for these same-named columns explicitly

[Apparently the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797403/sqlalchemy-error-please-configure-one-or-more-attributes-for-these-same-named) to that is to explicitly join the tables. But this isn't one!

It seems that this ought to be possible with 'mappers', but I can't find any examples that don't explicitly map to a 'table name' or its columns, which I don't really have here - it's not clear to me if/how they can be used with aggregates, or other 'virtual' columns from the query that aren't actually stored in any table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that what you are looking for is a [Query-time SQL expressions as mapped attributes](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#query-time-sql-expressions-as-mapped-attributes):

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, select, func
from sqlalchemy.orm import (Session, declarative_base, query_expression,
                            with_expression)

Base = declarative_base()


class Model(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'model'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    foo = Column(Integer)
    foo2 = Column(Integer, default=0)


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///', future=True)

Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(engine) as session:
    session.add(Model(foo=10))
    session.add(Model(foo=20))
    session.add(Model(foo=30))
    session.add(Model(foo=40))
    session.add(Model(foo=50, foo2=1))
    session.add(Model(foo=60, foo2=1))
    session.add(Model(foo=70, foo2=1))
    session.add(Model(foo=80))
    session.add(Model(foo=90))
    session.add(Model(foo=100))

    session.commit()

    Model.min_foo = query_expression(func.min(Model.foo).over())
    stmt = select(Model).where(Model.foo2 == 1)
    models = session.execute(stmt).all()
    for model, in models:
        print(model.min_foo)


with Session(engine) as session:
    Model.max_foo = query_expression()
    stmt = select(Model).options(with_expression(Model.max_foo,
                                 func.max(Model.foo).over())
                                 ).where(Model.foo2 == 1)
    models = session.execute(stmt).all()
    for model, in models:
        print(model.max_foo)
```

You can define a `default` expression when defining the `query_expression` or using `.options` with `with_expression` you can define a runtime expression. The only thing is that the Mapped attribute cannot be unmapped and will return `None` for `max_foo` as there is no default expression defined.